# The R plugin is not working in Pycharm 2022.3?

Tags: pycharm

I've used and been happy with the `R` plugin within either `Intellij` or `Pycharm` for a few years.  However the latest `R`/`Pycharm` combination is not working for me. I have installed `R` at least twice yet after restarting `PyCharm` as directed it still does not show up in the `installed` plugins.  I did not see any errors or warnings during the installation or restart process.

[image]

I am on `PyCharm Pro 2022.3.1` and have been attempting to install the latest `R` plugin - apparently version 223.8214.52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well OK that's strange.. I clicked `Install` yet *again* and this time `R` got enabled even without a restart.  I can see the `R` context menu options now

[image]